# How to enable TortoiseSVN real time status caching?

Tags: svn, icons, tortoisesvn, real-time, status

I want to see the overlay icons of tortoiseSVN changing in real time.

Like in the tortoiseSVN descriptions I enabled the "shell" status in the tSVN settings but it does not work.

I also tried another options and enabled and disabled all checkboxes....

When my colleagues commiting some new code into the SVN I still get the green "checked" icon over the specific folder/data.

Is there a way to handle the real time status caching. (If someone commits something that I can the see the result by refreshing the folder).

Or should we rather use something like Git(Hub) ? (It is all about default web development, so nothing special)

Comment: green means unmodified, so what is the point? If you haven't done local changes the green is expected. You also need to manually update the WC to download the changes from SVN server,

Comment: Right but if someone commits new stuff I would like to see the red (warining) icon so that I know that the file has changed. I only See this icon when I do changes and Do Not commit the file.

Comment: you misunderstand what the overlay icons mean (they reflect the status of you local working copy) and look for a different kind of software that notifies you about changes on server like [CommitMonitor](https://tools.stefankueng.com/CommitMonitor.html)

Comment: Oh... I thought the "shell" status caching would load the actual status from the "SVN directory" and overrides the status/icon of the local data... Thank you!

Comment: TortoiseSVN includes an utility called [TortoiseSVN Project Monitor](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-projectmonitor.html). I think that's the tool you want.